# How to get JSON response from API with multiple same responses?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make it make it return just the message ids (so I can check each one separately)

Here is my code:

```
@client.command()
async def inbox(ctx, username, domain):
    url = ('https://www.1secmail.com/api/v1/?action=getMessages&login=' + username + '&domain=' + domain)

    response = requests.get(url)
    ids = response.json()['id']

    embed = discord.Embed(description=f"Ids: {ids}")

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

If I remove ['id'] it works but will show all the headers etc

Comment: Coul you show whats in `response.json()`?

Comment: [{'id': 12345, 'from': 'example@email.com', 'subject': 'example', 'date': 'example'}, {'id': 123456, 'from': 'example', 'subject': 'example', 'date': 'example'}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you use `response.json()` - you receive an all JSON stucture that has been converted to python dict. I checked this endpoint https://www.1secmail.com/api/v1/?action=getMessages it returns the following JSON:

```json
[
    {
        "id": 639,
        "from": "someone@example.com",
        "subject": "Some subject",
        "date": "2018-06-08 14:33:55"
    }, {
        "id": 640,
        "from": "someoneelse@example.com",
        "subject": "Other subject",
        "date": "2018-06-08 14:40:55"
    }
]
```

So if you need to gather all `id` from list. You can use this approach.

```py
# I recommend you use a try/except block to catch the exceptions here
response_data = response.json()
ids = [message.get("id") for message in response_data]
```

Comment: Please format the answer somehow, this is impossible to read

Comment: I am sorry but I wrote this answer from my smartphone. From phone uncomfortable to format message. I think that author of question can extract useful information. I will format my answers next times))

Comment: Alright, then I'll do it

Comment: Thank you for help me

Comment: Can you send a description of error?